# NodeJS 20.11.0 NPM C-program error - Assertion failed: ctro->IsObject()

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

My goal was to installed LibreWolf on a Gentoo (linux) box until I enountered what seemed like a MakeFile issue.

I can see the issue is actually with NPM that is installed with Node version 20.11.0.
The install is attempting to install SafeMap and encountering a C-programming error.

```
user@gentoo ~ $ sudo npm --verbose install safemap

  #  node[48390]: void node::Realm::CreateProperties() at ../../src/node_realm.cc:72
  #  Assertion failed: ctor->IsObject()

----- Native stack trace -----

 1: 0x561d0ee75ac0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x561d0ee75b5d  [node]
 3: 0x561d0eef8ac4 node::Realm::CreateProperties() [node]
 4: 0x561d0edf555d node::Environment::InitializeMainContext(v8::Local<v8::Context>, node::EnvSerializeInfo const*) [node]
 5: 0x561d0ed9a77e node::CreateEnvironment(node::IsolateData*, v8::Local<v8::Context>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, node::EnvironmentFlags::Flags, node::ThreadId, std::unique_ptr<node::InspectorParentHandle, std::default_delete<node::InspectorParentHandle> >) [node]
 6: 0x561d0eec1c87 node::NodeMainInstance::CreateMainEnvironment(node::ExitCode*) [node]
 7: 0x561d0eec1db2 node::NodeMainInstance::Run() [node]
 8: 0x561d0ee3152b node::Start(int, char**) [node]
 9: 0x7f85de24dc8a  [/usr/lib64/libc.so.6]
10: 0x7f85de24dd45 __libc_start_main [/usr/lib64/libc.so.6]
11: 0x561d0ed8edf1 _start [node]
Aborted
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Using the recommended practices on the NPM website; however, all commands sent to NPM result in the C-Programming error.  Ideally, I would like to see NPM be managed by Gentoo's package manager Portage; rather than resort to Git installs etc.